# pre-commit additional_dependencies in a local repository

Tags: pre-commit.com

I'm trying to introduce `pre-commit` to our project. The project lives in a monorepo, and we would like to have all our checks to live in that same repo as well. We have a `flake8` plugin, and I'm trying to configure the flake8 to use that plugin, however I cannot figure out how to have `pre-commit` to install our plugin from the local repo.

I've added this to `.pre-commit-config.yaml`

```yaml
repos:

  - repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8
    rev: 5.0.4
    hooks:
      - id: flake8
        additional_dependencies:
          - ./my_flake8_plugin
```

But when I run `pre-commit run --all` I get this error:

```
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/Users/dtv/.cache/pre-commit/repo0620p39l/py_env-python3.10/bin/python', '-mpip', 'install', '.', './my_flake8_plugin')
```

I do realise that I could specify the absolute path to the plugin, but that will not work on CI or other developers' machines. I couldn't find anything about "variables" or "placeholders" in the doc (e.g. so one could write something like `- $(PROJECT_DIR)/my_flake8_plugin`.

Is there proper way of doing it apart from writing a separate `pre-commit` plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pre-commit will never install from the repository under test -- only from the configuration file (otherwise caching is intractable)

your best bet is probably to either package your flake8 plugin and install from a package index server or to utilize `flake8`'s `local-plugins` feature.

for example if your plugin lives in `./sub-dir` and is at `module.path:Plugin` providing code `ABC` you might set:

```ini
[flake8:local-plugins]
extension =
   ABC = module.path:Plugin
paths = ./sub-dir
```

in your flake8 configuration

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit and I'm the current flake8 maintainer

Comment: Thank you, the `local-plugins` option worked great

Comment: How would I do this for a "local" hook, rather than flake8. Surely the environment can symlink to it? Or is there a way to tell precommit to use a different venv?

Comment: @andyhasit it's not different