# Configure pre-commit to install additional dependencies consumed from pyproject.toml

Tags: pylint, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, pyproject.toml

I'm in the process of onboarding an existing open source project on pre-commit. The list of dependencies is tracked in pyproject.toml.
The pylint hook is raising an import error because additional_dependencies key is not populated.
Can I populate it with a value which references to a key in the pyproject.toml file?
The goal is not to repeat the same information in two different places. I'd like to maintain the list in one place.

I've searched quite a lot and reviewed the documentation with no avail so far.
Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pre-commit additional\_dependencies in a local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74329631/pre-commit-additional-dependencies-in-a-local-repository)

Comment: I'm not able to figure out how this link answers my question

Comment: the answer is "no there is no way"

Comment: i've googled a bit more and found this comment https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/1526#issuecomment-649938146

Comment: The following command is working: pip install ".[pyproject]", but not working when populating the additional_dependencies with ".[pyproject]"

Comment: How does your pre-commit hook for pylint look like? You can take a look how Pylint configures its own `.pre-commit-config.yaml` here: https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/blob/2c10a8517cef324376d8baf10c282c91315006a1/.pre-commit-config.yaml#LL79C19-L79C19  
It is used in GitHub actions then like this: https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/blob/2c10a8517cef324376d8baf10c282c91315006a1/.github/workflows/checks.yaml#L118

Comment: @LioraMilbaum yes of course, if you read the thread I linked above and the very first part of the answer "pre-commit will never install from the repository under test"

Comment: @dudenr33 Thanks as well. I was able to tag only one user per comment.

Comment: Somewhat crazy idea: You can create a local pre-commit hook which would parse the pyproject.toml and populate additional-dependencies field of .pre-commit-config.yaml . 

Note: I haven't tested this approach.